# Programmatically creating a rectangular Shape with a rectangular cutout for a Button

Tags: java, android, graphics

trying to make a rectangular ShapeDrawable that has a rectangular cutout - it needs to actually be cutout so that the middle is 'transparent', it can't be a white rectangle on top of a larger nonwhite one or something like that.

Here's what I have so far (all that can be seen however is the top 'bar' of the rectangle, which oddly enough is black despite that being the color of the cutout):

```
    PorterDuffColorFilter pd = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT);
    ShapeDrawable cutout = new ShapeDrawable();
    cutout.setBounds(top.x, top.y, top.x+cellLength*matCols, top.y+cellLength*matRows);
    cutout.setColorFilter(pd);
    ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
    border.setBounds(Math.round(top.x-thick*cellLength), Math.round(top.y-thick*cellLength), Math.round(top.x+cellLength*(matCols+thick)), Math.round(top.y+cellLength*(matRows+thick)));
    LayerDrawable ogre = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{cutout, border});
    Button test = new Button(this.getContext());
    test.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)Math.round(cellLength*(matCols + 2*thick)), (int)Math.round(cellLength*thick)));
    test.setBackground(ogre);
```

Comment: have a look at 9-patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a drawable xml :

**rect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#000000"></stroke>
</shape>
```

and use it like this:

```
test.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PathShape instead of the default rectangle in our drawable.  Add two rectangles to the path with opposite path directions, so that one will be cut out of the other.

Or you can divide your border into top, bottom, left, and right rectangles that don't overlap the cutout region.